# DbContext.Add fails on my PC but works on another

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, dbcontext

ATM i try to learn how to work with Databases. Now i want to work with the Entity Framework. I've made this simple sample and it does not work on my PC. It always crashes on db.Blogs.Add(blog); but it does not throw an error or anything else. I gave the code to a friend of mine who is also programming and if he runs the code it works for him.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var db = new BloggingContext())
        {
            // Create and save a new Blog 
            Console.Write("Enter a name for a new Blog: ");
            var name = Console.ReadLine();

            var blog = new Blog { Name = name };
            db.Blogs.Add(blog);
            db.SaveChanges();

            // Display all Blogs from the database 
            var query = from b in db.Blogs
                        orderby b.Name
                        select b;

            Console.WriteLine("All blogs in the database:");
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    } 
}

public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
}

public class BloggingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

I have no idea why it does not work and hope someone can help me.

Regards

Schlinger

Comment: where are you getting error??

Comment: are you absolutely certain there is no exception? have you checked your error logging or the event viewer to see what is happening?

Comment: That's the problem, i don't get one.. If i debug the code, it works till db.Blogs.Add(blog); after this line i fall out of debug and the console remains at this point

Comment: how long did you wait? it is possible it is attempting to establish a connection to the database but can't, and will keep trying until the timeout period elapses before you get the exception.

Comment: You right it throws the following exception after a while An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Comment: is connection string work for both machines?? or just you own that data server?

Comment: There is probably something wrong with your config file, can you show it? Also which database do you use?

Comment: Config File:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5"/></startup></configuration>

Comment: I worked with this tutorial step by step https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-ch/data/jj193542.aspx

Comment: Can you post your connection string and check if you have access to thej database that you are specifying in the connection string

Comment: I don't have connection string, what do you mean? All the code is below

Comment: @Schlinger If you don't have a connection string, that's the problem. Look at your program's `Web.config` or `App.config` and see if you have a `connectionStrings` section.

Comment: @Schlinger if you follow the steps in the section "Wo befinden sich die Daten?" of that tutorial, do you find any databases? Maybe you have just disabled the SQL Server on your machine.

Comment: There is no section like connectionStrings. But in the tutorial i used this was never said. Also my friend who tried it for me didn't do anything with a connectionString?

Comment: @ fuchs777 no i don't find anything... How can i enable it?

Comment: @Schlinger You can find the connection string by doing `db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString` in the immediate window. Ask the other guy to do the same and compare results.

Comment: @Anybody Thanks for the help. I could bring it to work :)

Answer (score 0):

Check your app.config. EF section should look like

```
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Comment: I pasted this code into app.config, now i get this exception: An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll

Comment: sorry, the closing tag for </entityFramework> was missng